# Springboot start manual Transaction to support optimistic lock feature for RabbitMQ event listener

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, rabbitmq

I am using springboot application which accept request either from Web or accept request from RabbitMQ listener.

Springboot version : 1.5.18.RELEASE

I want to prevent stale object update, so for that I use @Version to support hibernete Optimistic locking. And it is working fine when any request come from Web.

After search I found this is happening because of OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor (Referenc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html)

Now my service also accept request from RabbitMQ listener and update entity. So to support that I use **@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional** annotation on service method.

Here is the sample code.

```
1. class LeadController{
2.  .......
3.  updateViaWebRequest(lead); // works fine
4.  .......
5. }
6. 
7. class LeadService{
8.  //dependencies
9.  
10.     public void updateViaWebRequest(Lead lead){
11.         Lead persistedLead = leadRepo.get(lead.id)
12.         //update value into persistedLead usign lead
13.         leadRepo.save(lead);
14.         return
15.     }
16.     
17.     @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
18.     public void updateViaRabbitMQ(Lead lead){
19.         Lead persistedLead = leadRepo.get(lead.id)
20.         //update value into persistedLead usign lead
21.         //Save Lead
22.         leadRepo.save(lead);
23.         return
24.     }
25. }
26. 
27. class LeadListener(){
28.     ...........
29.     
30.     @Override
31.     public void onMessage(Message message) {
32.         //convert message into Lead class
33.         updateViaRabbitMQ(lead);        
34.     }
35.     ...........
36. }
```

Now assument At line no.20 some other web request come and updated the lead record, so the version is updated into database.

Expected Behaviour:

Line no.22 should give an ObjectOptimisticLock error. (But instead of this, it save the object successfully)

Does anyone know how to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not really using the version that is included in the `Lead` entity that you pass and it seems you don't fully understand how the entity lifecycle works, given that you try to save `lead` after you read from the database the `persistedLead` already.

If you want optimistic locking to work, you will have to merge the detached entity i.e. call just `leadRepo.save(lead);` and skip the other code before. If you don't want to do that, you will have to check versions yourself and throw an exception i.e.

```java
Lead persistedLead = leadRepo.get(lead.id)
if ( persistedLead.version != lead.version ) {
    throw new OptimisticLockException();
}
```

Comment: But when same request is comming from LeadController, it works as expected, I don't need to do any manual comparison during save.

Comment: Maybe because `LeadController` runs in a transaction and load that thing you pass in within that transaction? Then loading it again in your update method would simply get the same object.

Comment: When request is comming as WebRequest, Spring uses **OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor** this interceptor to start transaction, I have attached the link into question description for the same. But this interceptor does not come into picklist when I manully start @Transaction.